# Reason for the pointer is pointing to last character of the string literal in the 2nd case

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Case 1:

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int l=0;
    char *names[4] = {
        "Arijit",
        "Rohit",
        "Debojyoti",
        "Abhisek"
    };
    while(l<4)
    {
        printf("Address %u contains %s\n",names[l],names[l]);/*here instead of of names[l] for strings when I used names[l++] the memory order changed look at the output*/ 
        l++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output 1:

```
Address 4210688 contains Arijit
Address 4210695 contains Rohit
Address 4210701 contains Debojyoti
Address 4210711 contains Abhisek
```

output 2:

```
Address 4210695 contains Arijit
Address 4210701 contains Rohit
Address 4210711 contains Debojyoti
Address 45 contains Abhisek
```

Look in the 2nd o/p Debojyoti contains 10 character including '\0' so Rohit is assigned address 4217011. Why? Also look Abhisek is allocated to a memory location which is not consecutive to the other three names.Why?

Comment: thanks for editing @alk

Comment: Does the code in 'Case 1' produce 'Output 1' or 'Output 2'?  Which code produces the other output?  Using a `for` loop is often better than a `while` loop.  You should indent your code more consistently — it isn't easy to read.

Comment: Speaking of readability, using `l` as a variable name can be confusing.  Depending on the font in use, a lowercase L can look like the digit 1 or an uppercase i.

Comment: Don't print pointers with `%u`, the correct format is `%p`. A decent compiler with the appropriate warning options should have told you that.

Comment: @JensGustedt *Don't print pointers with `%u`, the correct format is `%p`*  That omits the result of using the incorrect format specifier: undefined behavior. For example, if arguments are pushed to the stack, if they differ in size the called `printf()` code will pop the arguments off from the wrong locations on the stack, causing incorrect results to be printed, or a `SEGV` if something like a `%s` argument is retrieved incorrectly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yes, but I usually don't try to scare people with UB, this is often not very constructive. The important part here is that using `%u` is an error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that C **does not define the order of evaluation of function arguments.** Period.  In most cases, C doesn't define the order of evaluation of operands to of a binary operator.

As a result, it's usually an error to both use and modify a variable in the same expression.  (For the language lawyers: No, I don't mean an error that the compiler will detect!  Undefined behavior situations are legal C, but the code is still erroneous.)

Your second-version statement, shortened, looks like:

```
    printf("%p, %s, %s\n", names[l], names[l], names[l++]);
```

C is free to evaluate those arguuments to `printf()` in any order whatsoever.  This means when `l==0` at the start of the staement, *any* of the following interpretations of that first iteration are possible:

```
    printf("%p, %s, %s\n", names[0], names[0], names[0]); l+=1;
    printf("%p, %s, %s\n", names[0], names[1], names[0]); l+=1;
    printf("%p, %s, %s\n", names[1], names[0], names[0]); l+=1;
    printf("%p, %s, %s\n", names[1], names[1], names[0]); l+=1;
```

On the same compiler, you could see different orders occur between debug and optimized compiles.  The middle two interpretations are unlikely, but still allowed in a standards-conforming compiler.  Only the 4th argument is guaranteed to evaluate to `names[0]', due to the definition of postfix`++`.

As I said above, avoid using and modifying the same variable in the same expression. *Strictly* avoid it when the order of operations is not guaranteed, and think twice even in the rare situations where only one interpretation is possible.  Guido Van Rossum (the inventor of the Python language) points out that programs are read more often than they are written.  There's a definite cost associated with confusing another programmer on your team--or even yourself in a year or two when you come back to edit the code.

There's an even more serious cost when "tested" production code starts failing after a compiler upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

using the following:

```
printf("Address %u contains %s\n",names[l],names[l++])
```

gives the results

```
Address 4195959 contains Arijit
Address 4195965 contains Rohit
Address 4195975 contains Debojyoti
Address 2973903200 contains Abhisek
```

why is that? because the names[l++] in this case gets evaluated before the names[l]. l get l+1 and when using names[l], the next l is used instead of what you expected. This is also why the last names[l] contains garbage

using the following:

```
printf("Address %u contains %s\n",names[l++],names[l]);
```

gives the (correct) results:

```
Address 4195952 contains Arijit
Address 4195959 contains Rohit
Address 4195965 contains Debojyoti
Address 4195975 contains Abhisek
```

Now the evaluation is done after both names[] evaluation

To avoid such cases, the best option will be to never make assumptions about evaluation order

Comment: could you explain why names[l++]  gets evaluated before the names[l] . @shlomi-agiv

Comment: @dumb_programmer *could you explain why names[l++] gets evaluated before the names[l]* No explanation is needed.  Argument evaluation order is completely unspecified in C.  The compiler is free to chose any order.

Comment: Now if I want to sort the string how can I do that?

Comment: @arijit you can ask that in a separate question, or better yet, google it